# if int(x)==int(q): NameError: name 'q' is not defined

Tags: python

Trying to finish my school project. Here's my code:

```
# -*- coding: UTF8 -*-
 import math

 def summary(lista):
     print("min: ", min(lista))
     print("max: ", max(lista)) 
     print("average: ", float(sum(lista)) / int(len(lista)))    

 lista=[ ]     
 while (True):     
     x=int(input("Enter number: "))    
     if int(x)==int(q):
         lista.append(x)
         print("Numbers on list:")
         print(lista)
     else:
         break

 print(summary(lista))
```

So as you can see I try to:

1. enter numbers to list
2. End the input process to press "q"
3. Finally show minium, maxium and average of the numbers

(lista = list, in english)

> NameError: name 'q' is not defined

any tips for this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you want to check `int(x)==int(q)` but you never told Python what `q` is supposed to be. The error message is crystal clear.

Comment: You can't cast x to an int before checking if `x == "q" `

Comment: somewhat unrelated comment, you don't need to `import math` since `min` and `max` are both *built-ins*

Answer (score 4):

1. `q` as is refers to a variable which you haven't defined
2. Your logic is wrong. The input process should end when typing `'q'`; which currently your program handles in a wrong way. You can do this:

   ```
   if x != 'q': # if the input is anything other than 'q'
       try:
           lista.append(int(x)) # convert to an 'int' & append
       except ValueError:
           continue # invalid input, start over
       print("Numbers on list:")
       print(lista)
   else: # break if x == 'q'
       break
   ```

Answer (score 0):

since the python interpret is unable to interpret the definition of q, you can simply make the following changes to your code,

```
while (True):
    q="q"
    x=(input("Enter number: "))    
    if x!=q:
        lista.append(int(x))
    else:
        break
print("Numbers on list:")
print(lista)
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do `if x != 'q'` ?